# .net core rc2 IIS7.5 returns blank page with Code 200

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, iis-7.5, .net-core-rc2, http-status-code-200

We have created a WepAPI with .NetCore RC2 including EntityFrameworkCore for access to our MSSQL Database.
When publishing this  WebAPI on the IIS on my localhost, it is working as expected.

Now I tried to publish my WebAPI to one of our servers, where the previously generated API (RC1) was running fantastically, the IIS responds with HtmlResponseCode 200 but shows nothing than an empty page for exactly the same requery that was working on my localhost.

We already installed the HttpPlatformHandler on the Server as well as on the localhost.
The only difference I am realizing is that on my localhost I have a VisualStudio2015 including `VS 2015 Tooling Preview`.

Any ideas how I can debug this blank-page error or is this an already known issue?

The apppool-user has rights on the folders, static-content is installed, databaseaccess is given as well, Fiddler just returns 200OK with text instead of json.

[Fiddler Image of the same request to localhost and to server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hEYd.png)